# Я хочу отправлять запрос на сервер с данными

Tags: vue.js, axios

У меня есть компонент регистрации, он должен после ввода всех полей отправить запрос на сервер по нажатию кнопки "Зарегестрироваться". Как мне это сделать?

```
<template>
  <form method="post">
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" value="">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Ваш пароль:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" value="">
    </p>
    <button type="button" name="button">Зарегестрироваться</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  mounted(){
      axios
      .get('http://10.27.1.9:5000/reg?login=!&password=!')
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

вместо ссылки в адресе запроса должны быть данные name и password

Comment: Читайте документацию по Vue и Axios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе надо навесить v-model на поля в которые ты вводишь данные.
И на кнопку обработчик событий

```
<template>
  <form>
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    <p>
      <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" v-model="login">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Ваш пароль:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" v-model="password">
    </p>
    <button type="button" name="button" @click="register">Зарегестрироваться</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register() {
      axios.get(`http://10.27.1.9:5000/reg?login=${this.login}&password=${this.password}')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]